# jQuery Unobtrusive Validation not working on html table - codepen

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

See my codepen here:
https://codepen.io/jquerypain121/pen/rNxgJgV

I am trying to get the fields within the table to also be validated upon submission of the form.

This is just a snapshot from my C# MVC application. The fields within the table are generated in my view with code like:

```
                <td>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Patient.Right["Sph"], Model.Patient.Sph_Dropdownnlist, "Select", new { @class = "form-control list-question-select" })                                               
                </td>
```

i.e coming from a `Dictionary<string,string>` property

What must I amend to get my table fields validated by jQuery?
Thanks

Edit - My ViewModel Code:

```
 public class Patient
    {
     
        [DisplayName("First Name")]
        [Required]
        public string Pt_FirstName { get; set; }          

    
        [DisplayName("Postcode")]
        [Required]
        public string Pt_Postcode { get; set; }    

        [Required]
        public Dictionary<string, string> pt_EyeDetailsRight { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public Dictionary<string, string> pt_EyeDetailsLeft { get; set; }


    }
```

In my Get Action method within the controller, these Dictionary properties are assigned keys like:

```
 model.Patient.pt_EyeDetailsLeft = new Dictionary<string, string>
                    {
                        { "VA", "" },
                        { "Sph", "" },
                    };
            model.Patient.pt_EyeDetailsRight = new Dictionary<string, string>
                    {
                        { "VA", "" },
                        { "Sph", "" },
                    };
```

This is then sent to the view, which is renders into Html like my codepen.

Comment: Show your viewmodel class. Did you apply validation for dropdown properties over there?

Comment: viewmodel code added. I haven't got any validation on the properties there, I think I have tried a [Required] in the past but that had no effect.

Comment: Did you add "Unobtrusive validation references" from Jquery?

Comment: It is in my _Layout.cshtml yes. 

The code pen is a simplified version of my View, and the Unobtrusive validation does not work on the table fields either.

Comment: Try to move Unobtrusive reference in your View page on top. Also use mvc helpers like `@Html.DropDownListFor`, `@Html.ValidationMessageFor` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

The issue was that span elements were missing for some of my select elements:

Updated codepen - https://codepen.io/jquerypain121/pen/rNxgJgV

For example

```
<span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Patient.LeftSph" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```

This was missing. After adding it after the relevent select elements, it was being validated.